# Multiple Apache with single PHP

Tags: php, apache, service, httpd.conf

I understand that I can install multiple Apache in one server and use the following code to set it as a service:

```
httpd -k install -n "Apache Instance x" -f "C:\path\to\your\conf file.conf"
```

I also read that to add PHP in the Apache, I have to set the conf with:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir C:/PHP
```

For example, I will have a three instances of Apache in just one server. Is it okay to load one PHP dll module in each of the three Apache? Or I need to have three PHP folders(modules), and then one PHP folder(module) should be designated to one Apache only?

..To explain it further:

> ONE PHP Folder Module will be used in three Apache

```
PHP
  ├------>Apache1
  ├------>Apache2
  └------>Apache3
```

> or...... One PHP Folder Module should only be used in one Apache

```
PHP1---->Apache1
PHP2---->Apache2
PHP3---->Apache3
```

I need three different Apache service, all with the same PHP version.

Comment: You should be able to use the same PHP DLL with all instances. Out of curiosity, what do you need separate Apache instances for that you couldn't achieve with separate virtual hosts?

Comment: @iainn: I am having problems with Apache if it's too busy. For example, a user opened a php file which needs to do a lot of script execution. And then another user opened another page which doesn't need a lot of execution time, the second user will wait for the first user script to finish before the second user's request will be done. So a way to fix this is to have three Apaches then use a load balancer. Or is there another way to fix Apache, so i just need one instance?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, your Apache must be horribly misconfigured if it is waiting for an unrelated user to finish before processing a new request. This sounds like some sort of file locking issue which user 2 cannot access because user 1 has it locked.

Comment: You don't need multiple Apache instances to fix this issue. Try running php trough FastCGI with a separate php process pool (PHP-FPM). This usually works much better, because apache itself doesn't get blocked by slow PHP scripts. You can also add multiple PHP servers (machines) with a single Apache instance this way.

Comment: I am really new with Apache. I use xampp for our current setup. What do I need to configure in the Apache of xampp so it can handle lots of scripts and users?

Comment: Apache is definitely capable of serving multiple requests at the same time - the MaxRequestWorkers directive (MaxClients in older versions) is what tells Apache how many "workers" to use in parallel. I'm not that familiar with XAMPP, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't configured without a sensible value (i.e. > 1) for this by default. A common reason that a thread would be blocked by another is if they shared the same session, but if it's a separate user then this shouldn't apply. You absolutely shouldn't need to work round a problem by running multiple Apache instances and a load balancer.